# SSRS Show all subtotals for each currency at bottom of report

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-grouping, subtotal

I'd like to show the subtotals for each group at the bottom of my report, rather than inside each group. How can I do this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create another dataset that subtotals by currency and add a table at the end the displays the results.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a second grouping to the table and group by your group. Right-click on the group --> Add Group --> Adjacent Below.

[image]

Then you'll have an extra grouping in the same table.

[image]

Or create a separate table using the same dataset but grouping by each group.